# bash: get a file name with a first line matching a string pattern

Tags: bash, find

How to find a file name with the first line matching a certain string?

So far I have come up with

`find . -type f -exec grep -l "MAGIC_WORD" {} \;`

but that searches for `MAGIC_WORD` across all lines of the files while I'm only looking for the files with that pattern at the first line.

I probably should somehow use `head -1` but don't know how to mix it with `find -exec` and return a proper file name

Answer (score 0):

This sounds crazy, because you want to read every file on the machine.

```
for filename in "$(find . -type f)"
do
   line=$(head -n 1 "$filename")
   if grep -q "MAGIC WORD" <<< "$line"
   then
      printf "$filename"
   fi
done
```

Where `-q` option is returning the exit status of grep. If I remember correctly, it returns **0** *(which means true)* if it finds the pattern or **any other integer** if it failed *(which means false)*.

What I did was creating a list with all paths of files and then for each one I check if their first line matches the pattern, if yes, I print the file path as well. I don't know if you need only the file name without the path.